# Preventing labels from overlapping in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

Im trying to prevent a mxd that has cluster of lables from overlapping these labels. What options do i need to select to ensure this?

- Labels have a prefered offset with a 500% Max offset.
- I have set the label buffer to 50% as a hard constraint.
- Label position is set to best. (I have tried different location settings)
- I need every label to be visible.
- Turning labels to annotation is not an option as the mxd is used to view results of ground investigation.

I have also tried different variation of the settings listed above.

[image: Example to the overlapping labels]

Comment: Have you tried both standard and Maplex label Engines (Customize - ArcMap Options - Data view)? You have more options with Maplex than standard

Comment: Yes, i have tried both and currently set up with Maplex

Comment: There is a limit to what the software can do with high density labels.  ESRI suggests in those cases that you use key numbering.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/key-numbering-about.htm.  If you don't want to do that perhaps you can try different fitting strategy options.

Comment: @johns I think your comment has enough content to qualify as a brief answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo i am unable to mark answer as accepted.

Comment: That's because there is currently no answer added to your question - only comments.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @johns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308187/preventing-labels-from-overlapping-in-arcmap#comment499007_308187):

> There is a limit to what the software can do with high density labels.
>   ESRI suggests in those cases that you use key numbering. 
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/key-numbering-about.htm.
>   If you don't want to do that perhaps you can try different fitting
>   strategy options.

[image: Image from ArcGIS help on Key Numbering]